# Nightwatch: is it necessary to .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)?

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm learning how to implement acceptance tests with Nightwatch, and in the examples provided in the documentation, it looks like they always use this instruction after they have called `.url(...)` or `.init()`:

```
.waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
```

However, it doesn't look like it's necessary. My test runs just fine using this:

```
.init()
.assert.visible('#user-login')
```

And that makes sense to me, as it should obviously wait for DOMContentLoaded before trying to do any interaction with the DOM.

But is it safe to omit the initial `.waitForElementVisible(...)` call?

Please note I'm only dealing with regular HTTP requests for now, no asynchronous XHRs.

Comment: In my experience, omitting .waitForElementVisible or .waitForElementPresent makes the tests flaky in that you're delegating the timeout to the assertion. These explicit waits are part of what makes Nightwatch more stable. A failure here means the test fails, and then retries. The time lost waiting for the test to retry is a tradeoff for not adding the wait for the element. My 2¢

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I just tried adding `setTimeout`s in order to make the page load for 5 seconds, and it seems like `.assert.visible()` patiently waits for the page to be loaded. What's the difference between having the `.waitForElement(Visible|Present)` method wait for the page to load or simply letting `.assert.visible()` take care of this?

Comment: Hmmm. In your specific case, I no longer see a problem with it. I was thinking that you were using assert.containsText, but in re-reading, I see no reason you can't safely omit it for just checking for visibility.

Comment: Oh, ok then. Thanks!